# Best practices for working with postman test collection json that is checked into git repo?

Tags: postman

We have a Postman test collection that is checked into our git repo.  Jenkins uses that to run integration tests in the pipeline.  If multiple developers need to add/update tests, what are the best practices to deal with merge conflicts?

From my understanding, the json export from Postman is machine readable only and manual editing of that file might cause it to break and not be imported anymore.

We can't get Postman Pro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are using a similar practice for the API testing in our team. There are some points which we learned and might be helpful.

1- JSON exported from Postman is not machine-readable only. you can edit it in your editor of choice (*e.g. Notepad++*) but you need to be careful as Postman expect it to be in a certain format to be able to import it. This is the procedure we use

- Pull the JSON files from the repo
- import in Postman
- Make the changes in Postman
- Export new files (including variable files) and push to the repo

Basically, Postman is the main development environment for adding/updating tests but small changes can happen by directly editing JSON files

2- Try to keep `request.json` file which contains the requests and tests as light as possible. The problem arises when you add more requests and tests to a single collection and it becomes heavier than the repository hosting platform(*Github, GitLab,...*) can load the file and it is difficult to review merge requests

3- To achieve above, find the parts of requests that repeated across the file and put them in `environment` and `global` variable files. If you already do so and still have large files, maybe you need to group the requests and put them in different collections in order to version control them more easily

Having said all the above points, resolving merge conflicts are still not very easy but not painful!

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I was initially against' manually modifying the json, but as long as it can be imported to postman and tests are executed.

Comment: How do you handle secrets, that shouldn’t be saved to  source control?

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim You could always use git pre-commit hooks to strip out secrets from JSON, replacing values with "<see value in LastPass>". However since Postman (now) is uploading all your secrets to their cloud servers, like it or not, the secret is now held by a third party.